# R: how to construct a mathematical expression from a character object?

Tags: r

In R, I'm wanting to create a graph with x axis label `expression(varname)`, where `varname` is a character object. For example:

```
varname <- "beta[1]"
hist(rnorm(20),xlab=expression(varname))
```

But that gives me a graph with `xlab="varname"` rather than `xlab=expression(beta[1])`. How to I convince `expression()` to evaluate the variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do by

```
hist(rnorm(20),xlab=parse(text=varname))
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be simple, but the help files didn't seem to have anything like it.

Comment: Mathematical notation can be defined as an expression in any of the text-drawing functions (text, mtext or axis). Output is formatted in a similar way to TeX, so for TeX users, this transition is easy. For a complete overview of symbols see the help file on `plotmath` and run the demonstration